# Is it possible that update (KB948465 - SP2 for Windows Server 2008) for DC could cause network problems?

Tags: windows-server-2008, networking, update

I'm not an administrator but software developer so pardon me if this question sound silly.

We have a client that having massive network problems that causes XP machines to timeout and break network connections and other problems with authentication (we have some LDAP based authentication services runnig on those XP machines). So few people ran all kinds of different network diagnostics and could not find anything wrong with hardware. The time problem started was correlated with the latest bunch of updates rolled on the primary domain controller (Windows Server 2008). Here's a list of updates:

```
Source    Description      HotFixID   InstalledOn             
------    -----------      --------   -----------             
DC1       Security Update  KB2481109  3/11/2011 3:36:42 PM   // security update for Remote Desktop client 6.1 and Remote Desktop client 6.0 
DC1       Security Update  KB961063   3/11/2011 3:36:43 PM   // * security update for DNS server - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/ms09-008.mspx 
DC1       Update           KB968930   3/11/2011 3:36:43 PM   // Windows Management Framework Core package (Windows PowerShell 2.0 and WinRM 2.0) 
DC1       Update           KB971029   3/11/2011 5:03:36 PM   // Update to the AutoPlay functionality in Windows 
DC1       Update           KB971513   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // Windows Automation API 
DC1       Update           KB971512   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // Windows Graphics, Imaging, and XPS Library 
DC1       Update           KB960362   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // Windows Ribbon and Animation Manager Library component of the Platform Update for Windows Server 2008 
DC1       Security Update  KB2416470  3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // ASP.NET security update - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/bulletin/MS10-070.mspx 
DC1       Security Update  KB976768   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // ASP.NET update for the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1  
DC1       Update           KB2117917  3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // Platform Update Supplement for Windows Vista and for Windows Server 2008
DC1       Security Update  KB983589   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // security update for the .NET Framework 2.0 Service Pack 2 
DC1       Security Update  KB976772   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // WCF update for the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 
DC1       Security Update  KB980842   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // * NCL update for the .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1  - http://www.microsoft.com/technet/security/advisory/973811.mspx
DC1       Update           KB979899   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // update for the Microsoft .NET Framework 3.5 Service Pack 1 (SP1) 
DC1       Security Update  KB979910   3/11/2011 6:14:41 PM   // security update for the .NET Framework 3.5 SP1 
DC1       Service Pack     KB948465   3/11/2011 6:59:08 PM   // ** SP2
```

People are desperate and want to rebuild that domain controller. I suggested to uninstall this last update (KB948465) that looks like SP2 for Windows Server. Is it that simple as going to "Installed Updates" and clicking Uninstall button on that KB948465? What could be possible bad consequences?

Comment: hmm a dc call dc1 love that name!  prior to the update being applied what was the last time this server had been rebooted.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a service pack so uninstalling it may take a while.  It is however possible you are getting issues because of it.  Do you have errors in your event logs?